# Как написать функцию через splice, принимающую массив и перебрасывающую первый элемент в конец?

Tags: javascript

Нашёл способы сделать это через shift&push, splice и slice. Но не могу понять зачем в методе splice нужны квадратные скобки после круглых "let spl = arr.splice(0,1)[0]". Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему без них не работает и показывает, что переменная spl равна Array(1), ведь arr.splice и подразумевает, что я хочу удалить один элемент, начиная с нулевого.

```
function changeSp(arr) {
  let spl = arr.splice(0,1)[0];
  arr.push(spl);
  return arr;
}

console.log(changeSp([1,2,3,4,5])); // 2,3,4,5,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что splice возвращает **массив** удалённых, а вам нужен один элемент - он извлекается из объекта-массива с помощью получения элемента по индексу [0]

Нельзя сказать, что без [] вообще не работает - просто получается в конце массива вложенный массив (содержащий один элемент).

Answer (score 0):

[.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) возвращает список удаленных.

Чтобы вставить переданный массив по одному элементу, можно воспользоваться [`spread` синтаксисом](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
function changeSp(arr) {
  let spl = arr.splice(0,1);
  arr.push(...spl);
  return arr;
}

console.log(changeSp([1,2,3,4,5])); // 2,3,4,5,1
```